# Multiple task with one

Tags: component, jform, view

I am looking for a way to build multiple task with 1 layout/view

for example:

administrator/index.php?option=com_component&task=form.one
administrator/index.php?option=com_component&task=form.tow

what i need is that from any task i can build the same form with different parameters

Answer (score 1):

Joomla MVC works based on task parameter, following a CMD string pattern. In this way, it can be associated with a controller/task.

A task array is not standard parameter, and Joomla MVC is not going to accept it, or call several tasks to compose a final output.

Tasks are executed by **JControllerLegacy** in this way:

```
public function execute($task)
{
    $this->task = $task;

    $task = strtolower($task);
    if (isset($this->taskMap[$task]))
    {
        $doTask = $this->taskMap[$task];
    }
    elseif (isset($this->taskMap['__default']))
    {
        $doTask = $this->taskMap['__default'];
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(JText::sprintf('JLIB_APPLICATION_ERROR_TASK_NOT_FOUND', $task), 404);
    }

    // Record the actual task being fired
    $this->doTask = $doTask;

    return $this->$doTask();
}
```

In theory, you can override all JController methods to override the default task execution, and create your own processing. Or, you can just add a new parameter **mytask**, and manage mytask in your own way to avoid any conflict.